# Subclass of UIView with CAShapeLayer as mask does not animate correctly

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, xamarin.ios, cashapelayer

I have added round corners to my subclassed `UIView` by adding a layer mask. The following is Montouch code, but should be easy enough to get the meaning also in ObjC:

```
// Add a layer that holds the rounded corners.
UIBezierPath oMaskPath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect (this.Bounds, this.eRoundedCorners, new SizeF (this.fCornerRadius, this.fCornerRadius));

private void UpdateMask()
{           
if(this.Layer.Mask == null)
{
    CAShapeLayer oMaskLayer = new CAShapeLayer ();
    oMaskLayer.Frame = this.Bounds;

    // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
    this.Layer.Mask = oMaskLayer;
}
((CAShapeLayer)this.Layer.Mask).Path = oMaskPath.CGPath;
}
```

I have overloaded the `Frame` property. Setting the frame adjusts the mask to keep the rounded corners in shape.

However if I animate the change in frame size, the mask is immediately set to the destination value of the animation instead.

Is there a way to make my view detect that is is part of an animation and make the mask animate correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is how CoreAnimation works for explicit animations.

With explicit animations, you never actually alter the values of your original objects, you merely animate objects in the presentation layer.   So you need to make sure that your object has been setup before you start the animation with the value that you want to have in the end.

A complete explanation of how to solve this class of problems is explained in "Core Animation Essentials" on the WWDC 2011 online videos.    Look for session 421

Comment: I watched the video. I'm not using explicit animations. I'm adjusting the UIView's property and this results in a change of the layer's property and that's not animated. I tried to animate the UIView's layer instead with no success: layers backing a UIView never animate. I can however animate the CAShapeLayer using implicit animation, but at the same time wile animating the UIView. I'm lost here...how can I combine both?